# Saving each line I read from a file as a different file

Tags: python, file-io

I am writing a program, which reads each line of a large text file and saves each line  as a separate file with the name essay.txt. That is, the first line should be saved as essay1.txt, the second line as essay2.txt, etc. Everything is working fine, except that instead of saving just one line from the document it is saving multiple lines.

Here is my code:

```
filename = r'/Users/d-sdf/test_erick/test/essays.csv'
f = open(filename)

a =1
line = f.readline()
while line:
    txtfile = open ("essay"+str(a)+".txt", 'w') # here I save each line as a file 
    a += 1 # This variable will change the file number
    txtfile.write(line) 
    line = f.readline()
    txtfile.close()

f.close()
```

Comment: I just tried your code on python 2.7.6 and it worked fine for me, It wrote the line to the first line of a new text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing this like it's C but Python's file API is much, much simpler:

```
with open('/Users/d-sdf/test_erick/test/essays.csv') as csvfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(csvfile):
        with open("essay{}.txt".format(str(i+1)), "w") as txtfile:
            txtfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module and always use the `with` context processor to simplify things. You don't need to bother with manually closing the file. The reason your code is reading the entire file instead of one line could be because the lines in the csv might not have been separated with a newline. Try opening in a different mode if required.

```
import csv

filename = r'/Users/d-sdf/test_erick/test/essays.csv'

with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    i = 1
    for row in reader:
        with open("essay"+str(i)+".txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(row)
        i+=1
```